# repopulate userform field with timedate

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, userform

I'm using Excel 2010 on Windows 7.

My userform contains a timedate stamp, it was working but now when I save the data the sheet, the timedate field isn't repopulating, it is a text field that is set to "now". I'm getting a Mismatch Error.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()


TimeDate.Value = Now
TimeDate = Format(TimeDate.Value, "mmmm dd yyyy hh:mm")
City.List = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A10").Value
State.List = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:B3").Value
Insurance.List = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C2:C7").Value
EBCAPServices.List = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D2:D3").Value
Patient.List = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D2:D3").Value
SelfEnroll.List = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D2:D3").Value
ContactType.List = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("G2:G5").Value
Staff.List = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("H2:H14").Value


End Sub


Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub


Private Sub ClearButton_Click()


Dim ctl As Control


For Each ctl In Me.Controls
If TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" Or TypeName(ctl) = "ComboBox" Then
ctl.Value = ""
ElseIf TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" Then
ctl.Value = False
End If
Next ctl
End Sub


Private Sub OKbutton_Click()


Dim RowCount As Long
RowCount = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count


With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
.Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = DateValue(Me.TimeDate.Value)
.Offset(RowCount, 1).Value = Me.FirstName.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 2).Value = Me.LastName.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 3).Value = Me.Address1.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 4).Value = Me.Address2.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 5).Value = Me.City.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 6).Value = Me.State.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 7).Value = Me.ZipCode.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 8).Value = Me.Phone1.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 9).Value = Me.Phone2.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 10).Value = Me.Insurance.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 11).Value = Me.EBCAPServices.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 12).Value = Me.Patient.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 13).Value = Me.Income.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 14).Value = Me.FamilySize.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 15).Value = Me.SelfEnroll.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 16).Value = Me.SocialMedia.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 17).Value = Me.ContactType.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 18).Value = Me.Staff.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 19).Value = Me.Notes.Value




.Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Format(Now, "mmmm dd yyyy hh:mm")
End With


If Staff.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please choose your initials."
Exit Sub
End If


If ContactType.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please choose the type of contact made."
Exit Sub
End If


If FirstName.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please enter a First Name."
FirstName.SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If


If LastName.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please enter a Last Name."
LastName.SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If


If Phone1.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please enter the phone number."
Phone1.SetFocus
Exit Sub
End If


Dim ctl As Control


For Each ctl In Me.Controls
If TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" Or TypeName(ctl) = "ComboBox" Then
ctl.Value = ""
ElseIf TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" Then
ctl.Value = False
End If
Next ctl




End Sub


Private Sub OnlyNumbers()


If TypeName(Me.ActiveControl) = "TextBox" Then
With Me.ActiveControl
If Not IsNumeric(.Value) And .Value <> vbNullString Then
MsgBox "Sorry, only numbers allowed"
.Value = vbNullString
End If
End With
End If
End Sub


Private Sub FamilySize_Change()
OnlyNumbers
End Sub


Private Sub Income_Change()
OnlyNumbers
End Sub


Private Sub Phone1_Change()
OnlyNumbers
End Sub


Private Sub Phone2_Change()
OnlyNumbers
End Sub


Private Sub ZipCode_Change()
OnlyNumbers
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line raises the error?

Comment: Private sub OkButton click...with Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
 ***.Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = DateValue(Me.TimeDate.Value)***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment because of I don't have a rep of 50, but I tested it and it works for me. One thing I did see was that this line

```
.Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Format(Now, "mmmm dd yyyy hh:mm")
```

makes this line

```
.Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = DateValue(Me.TimeDate.Value)
```

useless. The format line obtains the Date and Time from the Now() Function not from what is already in the field, there's nothing wrong with the code, but maybe look over your logic there.

It's like saying:

```
dim x as integer

x = 0

x = 1
```

Is x = 0 wrong? No. Is it pointless to have there? Yes.

Comment: Neither of those lines should have raised an error. I would want to confirm that there is not something else (perhaps the user is blanking out that textbox, or something else in the code is changing its value?